# Swiping up and down to move ARKit overlay in and out

Tags: swift, uigesturerecognizer, arkit, uipangesturerecognizer

I want to be able to have the user swipe up and down to move the object closer and further to the user's face accordingly live.

I accomplish zoom in and out similarly here:

```
@objc func handlePitch(withGestureRecognizer recognizer: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
    let tapRecognizer = recognizer.location(in: arView)
    let hitTestResults = arView.hitTest(tapRecognizer)
    guard let node = hitTestResults.first?.node else {
        return
    }

    if (recognizer.state == .changed) {
        let pinchScaleX = Float(recognizer.scale) * faceOverlayContent.scale.x
        let pinchScaleY =  Float(recognizer.scale) * faceOverlayContent.scale.y
        let pinchScaleZ =  Float(recognizer.scale) * faceOverlayContent.scale.z

        faceOverlayContent.scale = SCNVector3(x: Float(pinchScaleX), y: Float(pinchScaleY), z: Float(pinchScaleZ))
        recognizer.scale=1
    }
}
```

My attempt and moving it in and out:

```
  @objc func handlePan(_ gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer){
    gestureRecognizer.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1

    let results = self.arView.hitTest(gestureRecognizer.location(in: gestureRecognizer.view), types: ARHitTestResult.ResultType.featurePoint)
    guard let result: ARHitTestResult = results.first else {
        return
    }
    
    if (gestureRecognizer.state == .changed) {
        let position = SCNVector3Make(result.worldTransform.columns.3.x, result.worldTransform.columns.3.y, result.worldTransform.columns.3.z)
        faceOverlayContent.position = position
    }
}
```

It simply doesn't move the object when I pan.